Is there a proper way to include multiple exceptions in SPDX License Expressions?
After reading the ABNF in the SPDX License Expressions specification I don't see a way to apply multiple exceptions to a single license. The only way I can think of would be License-A WITH Exception-B AND License-A WITH Exception-C. Is this correct?
To be clear, License-A WITH (Exception-B AND Exception-C) is not a valid expression.

I would say: License-A WITH (Exception-A AND Exception-B)

@ruben2020 that is not a valid SPDX expression according to the ABNF syntax.

Yes that’s correct.
Another option (as of SPDX 3.0) would be to combine the two exception texts into a single text and then refer to that combined text using an AdditionRef. That probably requires a lawyer however (to draft the combined text), and (if the two exceptions are SPDX listed) loses some of the clarity of what you’re trying to express, so it’s by no means a “good” alternative. I’d just go with AND myself.
